# Callback with generic type parameter in Dart

Tags: generics, dart, type-parameter, dart-2

I'm trying to define a callback function that needs to accept a generic parameter and return a value of the same type. Keep in mind that the following example is an oversimplified version of what I actually need.

```dart
final T Function<T>(T value) self = (value) => value
```

This results in the following error, that I can't seem to get rid of.

```
The argument type '(dynamic) → dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type '<T>(T) → T'

dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

The only thing that seems to work is to give the value a type, but that defeats the purpose of using a type parameter in the first place.

```dart
final T Function<T>(T value) same = <String>(value) => value;
```

I need it to be generic so that the caller can pass the type it expects in return. I also need it to be stored in a variable, so I can pass it around as a callback function.

If this isn't directly possible, do you know of any workarounds? Thank you in advance.

---

Here's a more complete example if the requirements aren't clear.

```dart
abstract class Provider<T> {
  T get bar;
}

class StringProvider extends Provider<String> {
  String get bar => 'bar';
}

class NumberProvider extends Provider<int> {
  int get bar => 42;
}

class Foo {
  final T Function<T>(Provider<T> provider) provide;

  const Foo({ this.provide });
}

test() {
  final foo = Foo(provide: (provider) => provider.bar);

  String strValue = foo.provide(StringProvider()); // should be 'bar'
  int numValue = foo.provide(NumberProvider()); // should be 42
}
```

The annoying thing is that Dart actually understands that `foo.provide(StringProvider())` will return a string and that using `NumberProvider` will indeed return an integer, and yet, the error is still risen for the line where the variable is actually given a value.

```dart
final foo = Foo(provide: (provider) => provider.bar);
```

```
The argument type '(dynamic) → dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type '<T>(Provider<T>) → T'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that I can cheat the type checker by giving any concrete type when defining the value. Note that `dynamic` is not allowed, but anything else goes.

```dart
final foo = Foo(provide: <int>(provider) => provider.bar);
```

This both gets rid of the error and allows for the `provide` method to return the correct type when called.

In conclusion, this seems like a simple shortcoming of the type checker, not something that's actually impossible or difficult to achieve using the already existing language features. I will be raising an issue on the language's GitHub repository to allow for further investigation and discussion.

---

**Update #1**: the issue has been opened on [GitHub](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36749).

---

**Update #2**: the issue has been resolved, and it turns out that the behavior is by design. Quoting [Erik Ernst](https://github.com/eernstg) from the SDK team:

> Try this: `final foo = Foo(provide: <T>(Provider<T> provider) => provider.bar);`!
>
> The problem is that you're passing a non-generic function to the Foo constructor, and you should pass a generic function. There is no subtype relationship between a generic function type and a non-generic function type, so according to the type checker you might as well pass a String, and that's the reason for the 'can't be assigned to' message.

It turns out that simply adding `<T>` before the parameter list (instead of `int` as in the original workaround) solved the issue.

```dart
final foo = Foo(provide: <T>(provider) => provider.bar);
```

This forces Dart to understand that provider is of type `Provider<T>` and that the method will return a value of type `T`, saving us from using a concrete type and still getting rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a standalone generic function:

```
class Foo {
  final T Function<T>(Provider<T> provider) provide;

  const Foo({ this.provide });
}

main() {
  T f<T>(Provider<T> provider) => provider.bar;
  final foo = Foo(provide: f);

  String strValue = foo.provide(StringProvider()); // should be 'bar'
  int numValue = foo.provide(NumberProvider()); // should be 42
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this defines a function - one that you would use in a class, for example - not a standalone variable. I need this to be the latter so I can store it and pass it around as a callback function. I've added this remark to my original question.

Comment: Without your addition I had guessed that `self` was a top-level variable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion then, I appreciate the heads up. Your updated answer gets me closer, but still not all the way. Giving `Foo` the type parameter gets rid of the errors, but this way `foo.provide` just returns `dynamic` regardless of the passed parameter.

Comment: I've added my own answer as I've managed to find a way to cheat the type checker that gets me the results I needed. I appreciate you trying to help, in any case.