# Adding a void callback with a generic parameter to a function in Dart

Tags: dart, generics, anonymous-function

### What I'm trying to do

Given the following Node:

```dart
class Node<T> {
  Node(this.value);
  T value;
  Node? child;

  // TODO: add `visit` method

  @override
  String toString() => value.toString();
}
```

I'd like to add a `visit` method that will perform some action on the value of each node and its child recursively. Then I could do something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  final root = Node(1);
  root.child = Node(2);
  root.child!.child = Node(3);

  // one of these
  root.visit(print);
  root.visit((value) => print(value));

  // 1
  // 2
  // 3
}
```

### Naive solution

If I do the following, it works:

```dart
void visit(Function action) {
  action(value);
  child?.visit(action);
}
```

### Problems with the naive solution

However, the `value` in this statement is inferred to be `dynamic`:

```dart
root.visit((value) => print(value));
```

I'd like to infer it to be the same type as the Node's generic `T` type.

Additionally, the compiler allows the following, which causes a runtime crash:

```dart
root.visit(() => 42);
```

I'd like that to be a compile-time error.

### Attempted solution 1

If I change `visit` to the following:

```dart
void visit(Function(T value) action) {
  action(value);
  child?.visit(action(value));
}
```

Everything looks good at compiletime:

```dart
root.visit(print);                    // OK
root.visit((value) => print(value));  // OK
root.visit(() => 42);                 // error
```

But if I comment out that last one and run the code on either of the first two then I'll get the following runtime error:

> Unhandled exception:
> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'

I'm not exactly sure what that means.

### Attempted solution 2

Added `void`:

```dart
void visit(void Function(T value) action) {
  action(value);
  child?.visit(action(value)); // error
}
```

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
> Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void. ([dartuse_of_void_result](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#use_of_void_result))

### Attempted solution 3

This one was just a stab in the dark:

```dart
void visit(void Function<T>(T value) action) {
  action(value);
  child?.visit(action); 
}
```

The `visit` method seems to compile but calling it as before gives compile time errors:

```dart
root.visit(print);                    // error
root.visit((value) => print(value));  // error
```

The errors read:

> The argument type 'void Function(Object?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(T)'. ([dartargument_type_not_assignable](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#argument_type_not_assignable))

### Related questions

These questions seem related but I couldn't figure out how to extract a solution from them:

- [How to create a generic method in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004475/how-to-create-a-generic-method-in-dart)
- [Callback with generic type parameter in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848042/callback-with-generic-type-parameter-in-dart)
- [Dart: Type error when overrding generic function in abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642643/dart-type-error-when-overrding-generic-function-in-abstract-class)
- [How to check and cast generic parameters in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697189/how-to-check-and-cast-generic-parameters-in-dart)
- [Dart passing generic Function<T>(T t) seems to require cast, all other ways signatures don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361141/dart-passing-generic-functiontt-t-seems-to-require-cast-all-other-ways-sign)

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Attempted solutions 1 and 2 are wrong because they call `child?.visit(action(value));` instead of `child?.visit(action);`. (It needs to recursively pass the `Function` itself, not the *result* of calling the function.) Attempted solution 3 is wrong because it uses `Function<T>(T value)` (which doesn't make sense) instead of `Function(T value)`.

Comment: Also, you have another problem in that `child` is declared as `Node?`, which is shorthand for `Node<dynamic>?`.  You presumably want `Node<T>? child;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @jamesdlin in the comments for solving the problem.

You need to set the generic type for the `child` as `Node<T>`. Then you can specify the method signature as `void visit(Function(T value) action)` and pass `action` itself on to the child.

Here is the full example:

```dart
void main() {
  final root = Node(1);
  root.child = Node(2);
  root.child!.child = Node(3);

  // one of these
  root.visit(print);
  root.visit((value) => print(value)); // value inferred as int
  // root.visit(() => 42); // compile-time error

  // 1
  // 2
  // 3
}

class Node<T> {
  Node(this.value);
  T value;
  Node<T>? child;

  void visit(Function(T value) action) {
    action(value);
    child?.visit(action);
  }

  @override
  String toString() => value.toString();
}
```